# How to make three class thread of eachother

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I am building a project that watches for a change in a file, when the file changes it takes the last line of the file as an ID and uploads the ID to a DB once the ID has been added, a counter begins for a certain time X. below are my 4 classes to which work individually but im confused on how to use threads to:

1. When each process is complete start the next process.
2. When the whole process is complete restart the process again and wait until file changed.

Any help would be great, and apologises if my coding is poor, im new to all this!!

Thanks Jonny

The file watcher class.

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class watcherClock implements Runnable{

    static String clkID;
    static boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        checkFile();
        if(!done){

        }
        System.out.println(clkID);
    }

    public static String dancerID(){
        return clkID;

    }


    public static void checkFile() {
        try {
            WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            Path dir = Paths.get("/home/jonathan/Desktop/");
            dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_MODIFY);

            System.out.println("Watch Service registered for dir: " + dir.getFileName());

            while (!done) {
                WatchKey key;
                try {
                    key = watcher.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                }

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                    Path fileName = ev.context();

                    System.out.println(kind.name() + ": " + fileName);

                    if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY &&
                            fileName.toString().equals("example.txt")) {
                        System.out.println("My source file has changed!!!");
                        String sCurrentLine = null;
                        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/jonathan/Desktop/example.txt")))
                        {
                            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                                clkID = sCurrentLine;
                                System.out.println(clkID);
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        File inputFile = new File("/home/jonathan/Desktop/example.txt");   // Your file  
                        File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");// temp file

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

                        String currentLine;

                        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                                    currentLine=("");
                            writer.write(currentLine);
                        }

                        writer.close();
                        reader.close();
                        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
                        System.out.println(successful);
                        done = true;
                        }
                    }

                boolean valid = key.reset();
                if (!valid) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        checkFile();
    }


}
```

And the counter Class for the timer.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Counter implements Runnable{

   private static TimerTask myTask = null;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Thread count = new Thread(new Counter());
      count.start();
   }
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public static void CounterStart() {
    Timer timer = new Timer("My Timer", false);
  int count = 10;
        System.out.println("LIGHTS ON");
  myTask = new MyTimerTask(count, new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        System.exit(0);
     }
  });


  long delay = 1000L;
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, delay, delay);      
}

}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
   private int count;
   private Runnable doWhenDone;

   public MyTimerTask(int count, Runnable doWhenDone) {
      this.count = count;
      this.doWhenDone = doWhenDone;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      count--;
      System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
      if (count == 0) {
          getTimeStamp();
          System.out.println("LIGHTS OFF");
         cancel();
         doWhenDone.run();
      }
   }



  private static void getTimeStamp() {
          java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
  }  

}
```

The DB Connection class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Calendar;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl;

public class DbConn implements Runnable {



    public static void connection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("worked");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public  void connectionToMySql() {
        watcherClock id = new watcherClock();
        String host ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
        String username ="root";
        String password ="password";
        String dancerID = watcherClock.clkID;
        //System.out.println(dancerID);
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connected:");
             // the mysql insert statement
             String query = " insert into dancers (id)"
               + " values (?)";

             // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
             PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);
             preparedStmt.setString    (1, dancerID);
             // execute the preparedstatement
             preparedStmt.execute();

             conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println("Got an exception!");
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args []){
        Thread thDB = new Thread(new DbConn());
        thDB.start();
        //connection();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connectionToMySql();
    }
}
```

and Finally my Main class

```
public class Main implements Runnable{

    watcherClock wc = new watcherClock();
    Counter c = new Counter();


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread th1 = new Thread(new watcherClock());
        Thread th3 = new Thread(new Counter());

        try {
            th1.start();
            th1.join();
            th3.start();
            th3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to run these tasks on separate threads since they don't run concurrently (each task must be started when the previous one is done)?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve here?

Comment: i have an RFID reader that sends the ID of the fob to the file and the java program waits on the file and reads the ID. The ID is sent to a database that logs everytime the fob access the system. Then the counter starts Turning on a light and when the counter finished it turns the light off again. Then i can view at what times which ID's accessed the system through SQL queires.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but, This makes no sense:

```
th1.start();
th1.join();
```

It doesn't make any sense because the main() thread does nothing at all for the entire time that the `th1` thread is running.

If you don't want to do anything else while th1 is doing its work, then why even bother to create the thread?  Why not just do the work in the main() thread?

```
th1.run();
```

The entire point of having threads is so that different threads can do different things *at the same time*.

```
th1.start();
doSomethingElseWhileTh1ThreadIsRunning();
th1.join();
```

Comment: yes, obviously i am confused, and i dont know how to make happen the things i have described.

Comment: @JonnySmyth, you say you want to use threads, but what are the tasks that you want to perform in parallel?  Your description of the problem says, do this, _then_ do that, _then_ do the other thing.  Unless you want to do this _while_ doing that or, do this _while waiting for_ that; then there is no obvious reason to create new threads.

Comment: ok now i understand a bit more, sorry about the confusion so then my question would be how do i get this to run until finish...then restart the whole process and continously do that?